# how to setup percona pmm monitoring of percona 5.7 in docker container

Tags: percona, percona-server, percona-tools, docker

I want to monitor percona running in docker with the percona monitoring and management client.

I have percona monitoring and management installed, running and monitoring other percona instances (https://www.percona.com/doc/percona-monitoring-and-management/deploy/index.html). I recently added percona (currently version 5.7) running in docker container (pulled from https://github.com/docker-library/percona).

I found an open feature request to add the pmm-admin executable from inside PMM Server at https://jira.percona.com/browse/PMM-627

Is there way to setup to monitor my percona instance running docker?

Answer (score 1):

Can you show us the command you used to launch the Percona Server for MySQL 5.7 container? You need to ensure you are allowing access to 3306/tcp.

Otherwise from PMM Server perspective there will be nothing unique to your use case of running Percona Server for MYSQL from docker or via yum/apt-get, the mysqld_exporter will connect to 3306/tcp and collect MySQL metrics as needed.

You will be missing collection of node_exporter data so you won't have anything on your Disk Performance, Disk Space, etc graphs.